# Regex (Redshift) - how to get WHERE clause literals

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get the literal strings in this WHERE clause.

```
WHERE 
  variant_name = 'myvariant' AND tag_name = 'continent'
) rlac 
ON 
  m.lb_countrygrouping = rlac.tag_value_text 
  or rlac.tag_value_text = '*'
```

Using an online regex tool I managed as far as this rough effort :

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(ddl,'\n',' '),
  '(where)(.)*(variant_name)(.)*(=)(.)*(\'.+\')' ,
  1,1,'i'
)
```

Which returns :

```
WHERE variant_name = 'myvariant' AND tag_name = 'continent') rlac ON t.lb_countrygrouping = rlac.tag_value_text or rlac.tag_value_text = '*'
```

So I feel that I am at least in the right ballpark ... yet struggling to get to the goal !

Appreciate any guidance on how to isolate **'variant_name'** and obtain **'myvariant'**.

Thanks